# Issue with aggregate query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following data in a table:

```
 RIDER_ID, DEST1, DEST2, DEST3

 '864', '387', '24', NULL

 '864', '24', '1', NULL

 '864', '732', '1', NULL
```

And the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(RIDER_ID), DEST1, DEST2, DEST3, 

(CASE WHEN START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND ' 2018-11-01 23:59:59 ' THEN  COUNT(DEST1) + COUNT( DEST2) + COUNT(DEST3) END) AS '2018-11-01',
(CASE WHEN START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-02 00:00:00' AND ' 2018-11-02 23:59:59 ' THEN  COUNT(DEST1) + COUNT( DEST2) + COUNT(DEST3) END) AS '2018-11-02'

FROM SCHEDULE

WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-02 23:59:59' AND RIDER_ID = 864

GROUP BY START_DATE, RIDER_ID, DEST1, DEST2, DEST3
```

The result is as follows:

```
 RIDER_ID, 2018-11-01, 2018-11-02

 '864', '2', NULL

 '864', '2', NULL

 '864', NULL, '2'
```

However, what I want is:

```
 RIDER_ID, 2018-11-01, 2018-11-02

 '864', '4', '2'
```

So that RIDER 864 has a total of 4 destinations on the first date and 2 on the second date. Of course there will be columns for every day of the month and every RIDER_ID.

In other words just one record per RIDER_ID where the date columns contain the sum count of destinations. The values in the fields are index values and do not matter here. Just need to count if there is a value (meaning total destinations per RIDER_ID and DATES).

So far I have not been able to come up with the correct statement. Argh.

Comment: Your SELECT has 6 columns. Why do I see only three in the result?

Comment: You should only group by on the rider_id column

Comment: The first answer below covers it, but to add to their remark about DISTINCT. You appear to be trying to use it as though it were a function. It is not; DISTINCT operates on the whole row, over the entire result set (merging/removing duplicate result rows).

Comment: If it was me, I would start by restructuring the table

Comment: First off, your given data is insufficient; you mentioned `START_DATE` but it's nowhere in your given data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get what you want if you just remove DEST1, DEST2, DEST3 from both you field list and your group by clause.

the distinct(RIDER_ID) is not useful, as you are already grouping by that field.

However, even if structured in slightly different want, you may get a similar result with:

```
SELECT RIDER_ID, DATE(START_DATE) AS DATE_START,
COUNT(DEST1) + COUNT( DEST2) + COUNT(DEST3) AS RIDES
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00'
AND '2018-11-02 23:59:59' AND RIDER_ID = 864
GROUP BY RIDER_ID, DATE_START;
```

This should return your data in the format:

```
RIDER_ID, DATE_START, RIDES
'864', '2018-11-01', 4
'864', '2018-11-02', 2
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the columns in the result must be the dates when the rides happened. In essence this is a pivot SQL. I just can't quite get the results like I want. Yeah. I forgot to take out the extra 3 fields. I was doing some testing and copied over. However, it still won't give the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation, you usually need the condition *inside* the aggregate function, like so:

```
SELECT RIDER_ID
   , SUM(CASE WHEN START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND ' 2018-11-01 23:59:59 ' 
              THEN IF(DEST1 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(DEST2 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(DEST3 IS NULL,0,1) 
         END) AS `2018-11-01`
   , SUM(CASE WHEN START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-02 00:00:00' AND ' 2018-11-02 23:59:59 ' 
              THEN IF(DEST1 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(DEST2 IS NULL,0,1) + IF(DEST3 IS NULL,0,1) 
         END) AS `2018-11-02`
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-02 23:59:59' 
   AND RIDER_ID = 864
GROUP BY RIDER_ID
;
```

Also, while composing this I noticed SUM is probably more appropriate for what you want.

Sidenote: `CASE` is more portable than `IF()`, and can be nested. I used IF for better clarity in the example.

Comment: Hey this is what I needed. Tx